# Rewrite dry run PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed

Tags: maven, openrewrite, dry-run

When running a dry run for a recipe I am getting this error:

> [WARNING] Failed to access maven repository https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
>
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Wed Mar 20 18:59:59 COT 2024

The same thing is happening for Failed to access maven repository https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots.

I downgraded maven to 3.6.3 from 3.9.5 but this did not resolve the issue.
I am confused because I expected it to work with maven 3.6.3. Not sure if openrewrite uses its own version of maven.

Comment: I don't know what kind of repo `https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases` this is? The certificate on that site must be updated... you can't do anything here...

Comment: (@khmarbaise) okay, [that server now has an updated cert](https://crt.sh/?id=12514355997) issued about 14 hours ago -- but is apparently misconfigured; (at least one loadbalanced instance of) [it is serving a useless second copy of its leaf cert instead of the required and necessary intermediate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=maven.java.net&s=34.200.88.159)